# XML data parsing using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, xml-parsing

I would like to display XML data in table format, below is the code which I've written but it's not working. The data from XML is branched out and thus was not appearing completely earlier - but in my current code nothing is getting returned.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <style>
  table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  th,td {
  padding: 5px;
  }
  th{
  background-color:#BBB;
  }
  </style>
  <body>

    <p>Sample para  component</p>

    <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Click me</button>
    <br><br>
  <table id="myTable"></table>

  <script>
    function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          myFunction(xhttp);
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "sample.xml", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

    function myFunction(xml) {
      var a, b, c, d, e, f;

      function smartValue1(root, tag) {

        return (root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgName").length &&
          root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgName")[0].childNodes.length &&
          root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        ) || '';
      }

      function smartValue2(root, tag) {

        return (root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgCode").length &&
          root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgCode")[0].childNodes.length &&
          root.getElementsByTagName("InstructingOrgCode")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        ) || '';
      }

      function smartValue3(root, tag) {
        for (c = 0; c <= document.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioName").length; c++) {
          return (root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioName").length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioName")[c].childNodes.length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioName")[c].childNodes[c].nodeValue
          ) || '';
        }
      }

      function smartValue4(root, tag) {
        for (d = 0; d <= document.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioCode").length; d++) {
          return (root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioCode").length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioCode")[d].childNodes.length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioCode")[d].childNodes[d].nodeValue
          ) || '';
        }
      }

      function smartValue5(root, tag) {
        for (e = 0; e <= document.getElementsByTagName("FundName").length; e++) {
          return (root.getElementsByTagName("FundName").length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("FundName")[e].childNodes.length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("FundName")[e].childNodes[e].nodeValue
          ) || '';
        }
      }

      function smartValue6(root, tag) {
        for (f = 0; f <= document.getElementsByTagName("FundCode").length; f++) {
          return (root.getElementsByTagName("FundCode").length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("FundCode")[f].childNodes.length &&
            root.getElementsByTagName("FundCode")[f].childNodes[f].nodeValue
          ) || '';
        }
      }


      var i;
      var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
      var xmlDoc1 = xml.responseXML;
      var xmlDoc2 = xml.responseXML;
      var table = "<tr><th>Instructing Org</th><th>Portfolio</th><th>Fund</th></tr>";
      var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ClientInvestmentInstruction");
      var y = xmlDoc1.getElementsByTagName("Portfolio");
      var z = xmlDoc2.getElementsByTagName("Fund");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        table += "<tr><td>" +

          smartValue1(x[i], "InstructingOrgName") +
          "&nbsp; (" +

          smartValue2(x[i], "InstructingOrgCode") +
          ") </td><td>" +
          for (a = 0; a < y.length; y++) {

            smartValue3(x[i], "PortfolioName") +
              "&nbsp (" +

              smartValue4(x[i], "PortfolioCode") +
              ") </td><td> " +
              for (b = 0; b < z.length; z++) {
                smartValue5(x[i], "FundName") +
                  "&nbsp; (" +

                  smartValue6(x[i], "FundCode") +
                  ") </td></tr>"
              }
          }
      }
      document.getElementById("myTable").innerHTML = table;
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClientInvestmentInstructionList>
    <ClientInvestmentInstruction>
        <InstructingOrgName>Sample A</InstructingOrgName>
        <InstructingOrgCode>Sample A code</InstructingOrgCode>
        <PortfolioList>
            <Portfolio>
                <PortfolioName>Sample A Child</PortfolioName>
                <PortfolioCode>Sample A Child code</PortfolioCode>
                <AuthorizeFundList>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample A Penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample A Penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample A1 Penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample A1 Penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                </AuthorizeFundList>
            </Portfolio>

            <Portfolio>
                <PortfolioName>Sample B Child</PortfolioName>
                <PortfolioCode>Sample B Child code</PortfolioCode>
                <AuthorizeFundList>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample B Penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample B Penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample B1 Penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample B1 Penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample B2 Penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample B2 Penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                </AuthorizeFundList>
            </Portfolio>
            <Portfolio>
                <PortfolioName>Sample C Child</PortfolioName>
                <PortfolioCode>Sample C Child code</PortfolioCode>
            </Portfolio>
        </PortfolioList>
    </ClientInvestmentInstruction>

    <ClientInvestmentInstruction>
        <InstructingOrgName>Sample part 2</InstructingOrgName>
        <InstructingOrgCode>Sample part 2 code</InstructingOrgCode>
        <PortfolioList>
            <Portfolio>
                <PortfolioName>Sample part 2 child</PortfolioName>
                <PortfolioCode>Sample part 2 child code</PortfolioCode>
                <AuthorizeFundList>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample part 2 penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample part 2 penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample part 2a penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample part 2a penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                </AuthorizeFundList>
            </Portfolio>
            <Portfolio>
                <PortfolioName>Sample part 3 child</PortfolioName>
                <PortfolioCode>Sample part 3 child code</PortfolioCode>
                <AuthorizeFundList>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample part 3 penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample part 3 penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                    <Fund>
                        <FundName>Sample part 3a penultimate</FundName>
                        <FundCode>Sample part 3a penultimate code</FundCode>
                    </Fund>
                </AuthorizeFundList>
            </Portfolio>
        </PortfolioList>
    </ClientInvestmentInstruction>
</ClientInvestmentInstructionList>
```

Comment: The later portion of the code contains the XML content which I've used in the  code.

Comment: @nicematt — You are confusing the XML declaration (which is optional) with the Content-Type response header.

Comment: @Quentin I haven't seen the XML declared in the op... i'm always dumby >>

Comment: Thanks it has the <?xml> header. Any idea how can we display branched out XML data without missing any entry. As before using for in SmartValue function I was using exact location (eg [0]) , but that only returned the first entry not entire branched out data.

Comment: Where do you exactly have this problem? It's a bit hard to identify... just say the function which is executing wrong, for example.

Comment: I'm facing the problem inside smartValue function when using for loop for the last for functions and when I try to pass the value later on in the script. During debugging I'm unable to navigate to the issue. The final output I want is to display a table with all the values that are in XML file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You're ultrapassing a undefined index in the `smartValueN` loops, and you're trying to return values inside a loop, besides this the loop would break with `return`, and instead of getting elements by tag name in `root`, you try to get the same in `document`.

Solution for the `smartValue3`:

```js
var result = "";

for (var i = 0, p; p = root.getElementsByTagName("PortfolioName")[i]; i++) {
    result += (
        p.childNodes.length && p.childNodes[i].nodeValue
    ) || '';
}

return result;
```

And there's a typo in

```js
for (b = 0; b < z.length; z++) {/*...*/}
```

The `for` statement isn't expected in expressions where values are to be incremented, so:

```
 2 + for (b = 0; b < z.length; z++) {/*...*/}
```

results in this syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for
```

---

[image: typos]

but it's fixed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jgmw6we4/2/)!

Comment: Thanks @nicematt do you have a fiddle available where you might have tested it out.

Comment: @DeepanshuKaushik I'll make one... check the edit also :D

Comment: Yes I'm receiving the same error, but how shall we traverse through all the values for the branched nodes. If I don't use for loop it returns "0" as the value for both columns.

Comment: @DeepanshuKaushik You need to construct a string with each loop you made modifying the other strings such as `smartValue5(x[i], "FundName") + "&nbsp; ("`. I'm still doing the fiddle...

Comment: Can you please write down a statement with for loop using strings, I'm using this code: smartValue1(x[i],"InstructingOrgName") +
    "&nbsp; (" +
    
    smartValue2(x[i],"InstructingOrgCode") +
    ") </td><td>" +}
        for( a=0 ; a<y.length; y++){

            table += "</td><td>" +
                
    smartValue3(x[i],"PortfolioName") +
    "&nbsp ("+
    
    smartValue4(x[i],"PortfolioCode") +
    ") </td><td> " +}
for( b=0; b<z.length; z++){ table += "</td><td>" + smartValue5(x[i],"FundName") +  "&nbsp; ("+  smartValue6(x[i],"FundCode") +  ") </td></tr>"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120914/discussion-between-deepanshu-kaushik-and-nicematt).

Comment: @DeepanshuKaushik I updated the answer! See the link

Comment: Hi @nicematt can you please help me out here - I'm still stuck on this.
I want the table to be displayed exactly same as on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/daksh844/hrw85ck5/

Let me know if you think this is feasible. Thanks

Comment: Hi @nicematt Please refer to this question it contains both XML and JSON data file.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39038595/displaying-data-from-xml-and-json-in-table-format
Thanks.